# MSSQL query tuning

Tags: php, sql-server, union

I have the following scenario:

> 1 Client have 2 products lists (one common, one private), those lists have many products, some products can appear in the two lists. If the product appear in the private list, I want to get it, otherwise I'll take the one in the common list.

What is the fastest way to achieve this in you opinion ? So far I have tried the following:

- **UNION ALL** then remove duplicates in PHP (mediocre performances)
- **UNION** (poor performances)

Are there others possibilities to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle demonstrating what I have  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41d2e/2

In the fiddle I am assuming list id 7 and 1 as they are the list Id for customer 1, I used no join as I have thoses Id retrieved from php already.

What I need is to retrieve the product from the private list if exists, otherwise from public

Being more a mysql guy, I would normally do this with a group by without aggregate, so taht with the right order by mysql would simply cut the unwanted records (bad practice, but solid and performant enough):

```
select *
from pricelist
where listId in (1, 7) 
order by listId asc
group by artnum
```

So, for example, if I want to get all products for client id 1, I need to retrieve thoses:

```
ID  ARTNUM  ARTDES  LISTID  PRICE
1   1000    potatoes    1   20
1   1001    carrots     7   4
```

As the client 1 have 2 lists: 1 and 7 (potatoes appear both in list 1 and 7, so I just want the potatoes in the client private list, not the public one)

Hope I am clear enough, sorry for all thoses edits

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected output? Also please post what you've tried.

Comment: I have added a fiddle with a demonstration of what I need

Comment: Could you post your expected output?

Comment: yes sorry, let me update my answer

Comment: "some products can appear in the two lists" - is this the best design? Why not a single list with a new column with an enum for private/common/both?

Comment: I am developing a web interface for an old app with a ms sql database, I have to deal with thoses constraints. Sure design is far from optimal, but I really have no choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't figure out how to do this properly in pure SQL, I used a PHP method:

- Retrieve the two queries without UNION / UNION ALL
- Create 2 php collections
- Merge the 2 collections removing duplicates